# GetEnumerator realization within generic class

Tags: c#, generics, ienumerable, ienumerator

I have a custom array class `public class CustomArray<T> : IEnumerable<T>` with a generic property:

```
public T[] Array
{
    get;
}
```

How can I implement a GetEnumerator? What i have right now:

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
    return (IEnumerator<T>)Array.GetEnumerator();
}

IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    return Array.GetEnumerator();
}
```

But the first one does not pass the Unit test.
Result Message:

> System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 'System.SZArrayEnumerator' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator`1[System.Int32]'.

Comment: `.GetEnumerator` always prefers the non-generic version for backwards compat. You have to use `((IEnumerable<T>) Array).GetEnumerator()` (cast the collection, not the enumerator).

Comment: @JeroenMostert now I see. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is both `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` and `IEnumerabl<T>.GetEnumerator()` with the same signature, which would clash if they were declared normally.

Therefore, generally the former is added directly (being the older interface) and the latter is added as an *explicit interface implementation*, which can only be accessed by explicitly casting:

```cs
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
    return ((IEnumerable<T>)Array).GetEnumerator();
}
```

---

Side note:

Single-dimension arrays don't actually implement any interfaces directly anyway. This is because all the code that resides in the `Array` class has no knowledge of types or dimensions, and cannot access the array with static typing.

So [a class called `SZArrayHelper`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/aa97964558672440.html) implements all the interfaces, and the CLR is coded to use trickery to get the arrays to cast as if they were actually that type.

Answer (score 0):

First answer works!
All code:

```
 public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
            {
                 return ((IEnumerable<T>)Array).GetEnumerator();
            }
    
            IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
            {
                return Array.GetEnumerator();
            }
```